# Are Windows pages of memory always on a 4096 byte stride?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

On Linux systems, mmaped memory is always started from a new page of 4096 memory, as far as I can understand.

Is this also true for Windows OS?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: For Intel processors there are a limited number of page sizes depending on the processor, 4KB, then 2MB or 4MB.  See [page size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory))

Comment: There have been Windows systems in the past (the ill-fated Itanium line) that had page sizes other than 4KB.  There might be again in the future.  (I *think* the Xbox and Windows phones all use 4KB pages, same as x86 and x64, but I can't find a reference for that.)

Comment: @Barmar it may matter when trying to recover data from a failed drive image

Comment: @ChuckNorrris How would `mmap` memory alignment affect that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely, but call `GetSystemInfo` to be sure. Page alignment is equal to page size.

Answer (score 3):

It's managed by hardware.  Intel supports only a couple of page sizes, 4K, 2M.

Other hardware may be different.